# Limiting current with a shunt resistor

Tags: dc-motor, current-limiting, shunt

For my project, I am using a 3.3V source to run two motors. If the motors pull more than 1A, then they have to stop. I was told to do this with software and hardware protection. As a programmer, I have no clue how I should go about trying to design this circuit to stop just with the hardware. The suggestion I was given was to "think about shunt resistors".

Comment: What is the locked rotor current or coil resistance?  You can use PWM to control the concurrent and thus acceleration, or design a stall sensor and measure current limit then stop immediately, coast or reverse motor acceleration with a full bridge driver. You decide

Comment: I think you should add some more details to the question. Currents involved, as mentioned by Tony. Motor type: DC, stepper etc. And also what kind of means of monitoring you have, just digital IO pins or ADC.

Comment: If you already know how to program you can control an incredible variety of systems just by learning how to use sense circuits and how to control switches.  The disadvantage is that a CPU is sequential and depending on what else it's doing there's a limit to how often it can "look at" or change the parameters of a load.  Another advantage if you know how to program is you can often replace a whole bunch of chips totalling $10 or $20 or more with a single $2-$3 microcontroller.

Comment: Resistors are reliable, but their main disadvantage is they do what they do (control current in this case)by wasting power, so I just want to emphasize Tony's comment about PWM because it's very easy to do in programming and far better than a resistor.  That said, you'd still put a much smaller resistor on the line to use to measure current.

Answer (score 2):

A shunt resistor (despite the name*) is a resistor in **series** with the load. By measuring the voltage across a shunt resistor (which should be as low as practical to avoid wasting power in the resistor and depriving the motor of voltage) you can determine the current. There are also DC current sensors that use other principles.

Once you have a current measurement (or a binary indication that it has exceeded a limit) then you can deal with it one way or another. If the current needs to be cut off very promptly, many MCU PWM peripherals have an optional hardware input that can be configured to shut down the output virtually instantly, for just this purpose.

* I assume that they are called "shunt" resistors because they would have been connected across a meter movement.